# Hyperlinking to points in the middle of questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20131063/2707864), for which I received two answers. [One of them (currently answer #2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132770/2707864) is particularly long (and very well explained). I would like to post another answer with further info, an elaboration of the two answers, etc.

To improve readability of my answer, I would like to be able to hyperlink to a point in the middle of answer #2, not to its beginning (it would be almost useless in this case). In other cases, it might be convenient to link to points in the middle of other questions, or in answers to different questions.

Then, I propose that hyperlinking to points in the middle of questions/answers is allowed.

Comment: +1 I thought about hyperlinks to a specific line somewhere else too!